# Extract and store a specific position from multiple matrices in an array in R

Tags: r, for-loop, data-extraction

Sorry, newbie...
I've got an array object called "y" of 500 matrices of 6x6, like this:

```
, , 1
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]
[1,] 0.0000 0.3627 0.4132 0.4231 0.3795 0.5444
[2,] 0.3627 0.0000 0.2084 0.3523 0.2310 0.5377
[3,] 0.4132 0.2084 0.0000 0.1984 0.2920 0.4774
[4,] 0.4231 0.3523 0.1984 0.0000 0.2787 0.4363
[5,] 0.3795 0.2310 0.2920 0.2787 0.0000 0.5129
[6,] 0.5444 0.5377 0.4774 0.4363 0.5129 0.0000

[...]

, , 500
       [,1]   [,2]   [,3]   [,4]   [,5]   [,6]
[1,] 0.0000 0.3755 0.3568 0.3835 0.3582 0.5065
[2,] 0.3755 0.0000 0.0840 0.2253 0.2237 0.4066
[3,] 0.3568 0.0840 0.0000 0.1673 0.2434 0.4073
[4,] 0.3835 0.2253 0.1673 0.0000 0.2338 0.3403
[5,] 0.3582 0.2237 0.2434 0.2338 0.0000 0.4263
[6,] 0.5065 0.4066 0.4073 0.3403 0.4263 0.0000
```

I want to extract a specific position through all the 500 matrices in the array and store this 500 values in a vector named "unouno" for further analyses

I'm trying to do this:

```
for (i in 1:dim(y)[[3]]){
unouno<-y[2,1,i, drop=F]
}
```

but it only extracts the value for the last (500th) matrix.

(Once solved this I want to extract and store separately the 500 values of each of the 6 x 6 positions in the matrices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would like to fix your loop, this could be one way to do it:

```
unouno <- NULL
for (i in 1:dim(y)[3]){
  unouno[i]<-y[2,1,i]
}
```

It seems that you were mising indexing on the vector unouno as well

Comment: Exactly... I was missing the index in the vector

Comment: OK, now I have all the 500 values for the position 1,1 (unouno) of the 500 matrices. If the matrices are 6 x 6 I have to do this 36 times (1,1;2,1, 3,1;...;6,6).

Comment: The indexing should be working, but you could try putting in parenthesis the index plus one, in the for loop call

Comment: I'm trying several things to do the same 36 times. I ve tried to nest a loop to vary the other array positions, but not sucessfull. Any suggestion to keep on fighting...?? With 6x6 matrices I could write this 36 times, but I have 20x20 matrices and write the 400 times is out of question.

Comment: as per the forum's rules, it is customary to ask one question per issue (as to give others the chance to see and learn/contribute), but it seems that, if you want to nest this, you would have to index twice (`i` and `j`) and nest the loops accordingly

Comment: the first solution worked perfectly. Thanks! ok I'll ask this in another clean question.

Answer (score 2):

We can do this by leaving the 3rd dimension blank

```
y[2,1,]
```

#### data

```
y <- array(1:60, dim=c(10,2,3))
```